# Remove routing path from Kubernetes ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed service called "test" in kubernetes. 
  service name : test
  port : 80

There is endpoint called "/abc"

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: load-balancer

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test/*
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

API call "http://ip-address/test/abc" given 404 error. But endpoint "/test/abc" working properly.

I need skip "/test" when routing.
How I do this.

Comment: do you mean that you want to access the files at /test/abc but you only want to use 'http://ip-address/abc' ? Or have you moved the files out of the /test directory and need to update the ingress?

Comment: What do you mean by "skip /test"?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. "Skip /test" means my REST endpoint should be "/abc" and request URL should be "http://ip-address/test/abc". Have any modification in ingress

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

In this ingress definition, any characters captured by (.*) will be assigned to the placeholder $2, which is then used as a parameter in the rewrite-target annotation.

For example:

- `rewrite.bar.com/something` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md.

Comment: I know it's old but saved my day in very big way. At least my Java services are up now. Yet to deal with NextJS :)

Comment: Isn't `pathType` missing? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types

Answer (score 13):

You're looking for url rewriting feature. It's currently only supported on nginx-ingress (not GKE ingress). https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md.

But you can install nginx-ingress controller on GKE if you want, there's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I go through the document and follow the given steps. But raised error when "Deploy NGINX Ingress Controller". when running "helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true" command it given error as "Error: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials".

Comment: That's a separate problem.

Comment: Traefik.io is another option that has the same capabilities with its own CustomResourceDefinitions for routing.