# Ingress URL and applications URL - how does it work together?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I apologize for the confusion, I hope I am not missing something.

I am trying to understand the way I forward http request through ingress in Kubernetes cluster.
I have a spring-boot microservice. if I run an image of it locally (NOT IN KUBERNETES)then I would send the following HTTP request:

```
  http://localhost:8088/reader/info
```

and get the response. it uses the port 8088 and has "reader/info " API defined in it.

**Now moving forward to Kubernetes:**

I have deployed:

1. ingress resource
2. deployment of my application (same microservice that works with     http://localhost:8088/reader/info locally and not in Kubernetes)
3. service of type clusterIP for my application

**in the ingress resource:**
I have defined the host name: **debug.com**, and I would like the requests to be forwarded to service "reader-service".

my question is: how do I forward the request **"reader/info"** to the service through ingress(which is the original path that the application expects)? do I need to define that URL reader/info in the ingress itself? or in the parameters of the request?
what should be in the URL that I send? because obviously I can have 100 microservices with completely different URL.

obviously, I am missing something here..

**Ingress resource**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1  
kind: Ingress
   
metadata:
   
  name: ingress-rules
  namespace: default
    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules: 
    - host: debug.com
      http:  
        paths:  
          - path: /  
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:  
              service: 
                name: reader-service 
                port:
                  #same port of clusterIp
                   number: 80
          
          - path: /search
            pathType: Prefix  
            backend:  
              service: 
                name: reader-service
                port:
                  #same port of clusterIp
                  number: 80
```

**deployment + service:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

 kind: Deployment

 metadata:
   name: reader-deployment
   labels: 
    app: reader

 spec:

   replicas: 3
   selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: reader
      version: v1
   
   template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reader
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: reader
        image: artifactory-iky.com:5654/reader:v1.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8088       
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrykey
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 

metadata:
  name: reader-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP

  selector:
    app: reader

  ports:
    - targetPort:  8088
      port: 80
```

Comment: The path is passed through automatically. Are you saying it isn't working?

Comment: I think I might got confused with host name and path.. it's the same host name but different paths, and in the path, I should place the path of the microservice API?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is:

1. Configure your applications to work without path (at location "/").
2. Configure Ingress with desired application path.
3. Configure Ingress to strip path in the requests to the backend.

See: [Remove routing path from Kubernetes ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923298/remove-routing-path-from-kubernetes-ingress)

Of course, You can use the application path in the Ingress configuration or you can rewrite the location to the application path, but then you'll have to configure each application rewrite rule.