# Nginx Ingress path rewriting does not forward to specified endpoint in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In our Kubernetes Cluster we have a micro frontend, which is accessable under image-self-service:8080 without any additional path. To be able to use it in a bigger application I want to use an Nginx-Ingress to reroute from url-to-site/profile to image-self-service:8080/.

I have found and read this SO post, thats basically asking the same thing:
[Remove routing path from Kubernetes ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923298/remove-routing-path-from-kubernetes-ingress) and the linked documentation here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md

which resulted in me using a .yaml for my Ingress that looks like this: (sensitive Information removed)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure    
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: intranet-backend-ingress
  namespace: intranet


spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxx-test.xxx.xxx
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: image-self-service
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /profile(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: intranet-ui
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
    ...
```

For readability I also removed other endpoints which are more specific as I don't think those interfere.
I have tried using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`

If I remove the rewrite-target and add a specific path, the forwarding works but with the additional path, so it results in a 404 from the underlying webservice. The Response I get using the rewriting is simply: `404 page not found` which I believe to be an Ingress message.

Comment: Can you check in the destination service logs which url provoke the 404 ?

Comment: @jujule What exactly do you mean? The logs of the Ingress 'pod'?

Comment: yes; does the pod itself receive the request. if so, does it point to the  /profile/test subpath ?

Comment: The "image-self-service" pod does not receive the request. I will add the logs of the Ingress as soon as I get them from my boss.